# regarding app.config

Tags: c#

I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="FBI" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <FBI>
    <add key="FilePath" value="D:\C Drive\Desktop\test1.txt"/>
  </FBI>
<configuration>
```

in `app.config`..

And I set the `Copy to Output Directory` for `app.config` to copy if newer.

In the program,

```
   var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FBI") as NameValueCollection;
            FilePath.Text = section["FilePath"];
```

where `FilePath` is a label.

When I change the config file to

```
D:\C Drive\Desktop\test2.txt
```

and build using VS (release mode), it shows correctly as

```
D:\C Drive\Desktop\test2.txt
```

But if I change the app.config in release folder to

```
D:\C Drive\Desktop\test3.txt
```

and run using the exe file in the release folder directly, it still shows me

```
D:\C Drive\Desktop\test1.txt
```

without updating to `test3.txt`

What's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I set the Copy to Output Directory for app.config to copy if newer.

You don't need to do this: it will be copied automatically to `AppName.exe.config` in the output folder.  And it's this file you need to modify.